# Which model is the bluetooth chip in bluetooth adapter?

Tags: bluetooth

There are many models of bluetooth produced by realtek such as rtl8725,rtl8761,rtl8821.I have a usb blue adapter,i want to know which model is the bluetooth chip in bluetooth adapter?

```
sudo  dmesg | grep -i tooth
[    2.778424] usb 2-10: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[   10.918815] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   10.918832] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   10.918834] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   10.918836] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   10.918840] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   11.298374] rtk_btusb: Realtek Bluetooth USB driver ver 3.1.244af65.20200812-195650
[   19.222345] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   19.222346] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   19.222350] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   55.326843] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   55.326846] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   55.326850] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

I collect some realtek bluetooth models from web:

```
rtl8723b_fw
rtl8723d_fw
rtl8723fs_fw
rtl8725as_fw
rtl8761a_fw
rtl8761at8192ee_fw
rtl8761b_fw
rtl8821a_fw
rtl8821c_fw
rtl8822b_fw
rtl8822cs_fw
```

Show my usb device:

```
lsusb 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 17ef:6019 Lenovo 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0d28:0204 NXP ARM mbed
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2bdf:0284  
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

No model number 8771 in realtek's bluetooth chip.
How to get exactly which model it is.

Comment: Run `lsusb` and you should have information about the chip.

Comment: The model is `8761B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model of your BT chip is `8761B`.

If you are interested in firmware for this device, you need:

```
rtl8761b_fw.bin
rtl8761b_config
```

But these files have not been added to `linux-firmware` yet.

[Source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btrtl.c?h=v5.10.10&id=04896832c94aae4842100cafb8d3a73e1bed3a45)

Comment: No 8761 as my command's output,it is your guess.

Comment: I don't guess. The PID of your device is `8771`. It means that it is `8761B`. I added a link to the kernel commit adding support for it.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using usb adapter for Bluetooth, it must be [   11.298374] rtk_btusb: Realtek Bluetooth USB driver ver 3.1.244af65.20200812-1956

Comment: It is the driver version:3.1.244af65.20200812-1956 ,instead of bluetooth chip's model.